# Geetest solver using 2captcha + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, 2captcha

I am using selenium to load the target page, then using 2catpcha to solve geetest, after success solve, I get data from 2captcha

> "geetest_challenge", "geetest_validate","geetest_seccode"

But then I dont know how to submit these data to my target page.
What should I do? I am using python language

Comment: full response from 2captcha
{'captchaId': '71847496111', 'code': '{"geetest_challenge":"78fe4538be7881df9eb9ad3a3f3c120b","geetest_validate":"268e0166a999053b2531101dc464ca60","geetest_seccode":"268e0166a999053b2531101dc464ca60|jordan"}'}

Comment: What is your target page?

Comment: https://www.okx.com/account/login
here is my target page